# Randers space and a Finsler space

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, definition, finsler-geometry

What is the difference between  Randers spaces and  Finsler spaces?

Comment: Why is the question (v3) closed? The question seems clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. A [Randers manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finsler_manifold#Randers_manifolds) is a special case of a non-reversible [Finsler manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finsler_manifold) $(M,F)$, where the Finsler function 
   $$F(x,v)~=~\sqrt{g_{ij}(x)v^iv^j}+b_i(x)v^i, \qquad  (g^{-1})^{ij}b_ib_j~<~1,$$ 
   is a sum of a square root term and linear term.
2. a [Riemannian manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_manifold) $(M,g)$ is a Randers manifold with $b_i\equiv 0$.